# Get array of index from multiple tables inside Datatable

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, datatable

I am building an application that goes to excel to fetch several tables inside a sheet, it is known that the tables are divided by an empty column. I imported the sheet into a datatable, and now I'm trying to build an index array to get the limits of tables and export to other datatable.

```
ArrIndex[0,0] = 1,1
ArrIndex[0,1] = 1,3
ArrIndex[1,0] = 4,0
ArrIndex[1,1] = 4,4
```

The datatable is like this:

```
  A  B  C  D    A  B  C  D  E    A  B  C
1 V  V  V  V    V  V  V  V  V    V  V  V
2 V  V  V  V    V  V  V  V  V    V  V  V
3 V  V  V  V    V  V  V  V  V    V  V  V
4 V  V  V  V    V  V  V  V  V    V  V  V
```

and now i want do have the bounds of first table to fill a new datatable like this:

```
  A  B  C  D 
1 V  V  V  V 
2 V  V  V  V 
3 V  V  V  V 
4 V  V  V  V
```

At this time is a litle confuse
I have this function:

> ```
> public void ImportTablesToSQL(DataTable DT)
>         {
>             //Array to know when start and end etch table
>             int[,] TablesIndex = new int[1, 1];
>
>             int[,] ColumnBefore = new int[1,1];
>             int counteri = 1;
>             int counterj = 1;
>             //Get the index of tables
>
>
>
>             for (int j = 0; j>=DT.Columns.Count; j++)
>                 {
>
>                 if ((counteri == 0) && counterj == 0 )
>                 {
>                     TablesIndex[counteri, counterj] = {0,0};
>
>                 }
>
>                     if ((DT.Rows[0][j].ToString() == "") && (DT.Rows[0][j - 1].ToString() != "") &&( DT.Rows[0][j + 1].ToString() != ""))
>
>                 {
>                     //recive bounders of table
>
>                     TablesIndex[counteri, counterj] = j;
>                 }
>                 }  
>         }
> ```

Comment: So you have tried something but you got stuck somewhere. What was it, why you couldn't finish this task? Can you show your attempt? Then we could help to fix it

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do and we cannot help you without a code sample of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I already put the code that i have. My problem is to get the limits of eatch table into datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours the return of this I was able to solve. 
I'll post my solution here if anyone needs it:

```
DT.Rows.Add(); //Add new line to get last line of table without errors
        DT.Rows.Add(); //Add new line to get last line of table without errors
        DT.Columns.Add(); //Add new column to get last column wihout errors
        DT.Columns.Add();//Add new column to get last column wihout errors

        //Array to know when start and end etch table
        int[,] TablesIndex = new int[1, 6]; //Array to save matriz of each table
        //[X,0] = Coluna inicial
        //[X,1] = Linha inicial
        //[X,2] = Coluna final
        //[X,3] = Linha final

        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        bool Entra = true;
        bool UltimaTabela = false;
        //Get the index of tables



        for (int j = 1; j<=DT.Columns.Count-2; j++)
            {

            if ((x == 1) && (y == 1) && (Entra == true))
            {
                //Coluna inicio
                TablesIndex[0, 0] = 0;
                //Linha Inicio
                TablesIndex[0 , 1] = 4;
                Entra = false;
            }
            else if (Entra == true)
            {
                //Coluna Fim tabela anterior
                TablesIndex[x-1 , 0] = TablesIndex[x-2, 2] + 2;
                //Linha Inicio
                TablesIndex[x-1, 1] = 4;
                Entra = false;


            }

                if (DT.Rows[5][j - 1].ToString() == "Total")//é sempre o ultima coluna

            {
                //se nao for a ultima tabela
                if ((DT.Rows[5][j].ToString() == "")&&(DT.Rows[5][j + 1].ToString() != ""))
                {
                    //Coluna Fim
                    TablesIndex[x - 1, 2] = j - 1;
                }

                //Se for a ultima tabela 
                if (DT.Columns.Count - 2 == j)
                {
                    //Coluna Fim
                    TablesIndex[x - 1, 2] = j-1;
                    UltimaTabela = true;
                }

                for (int k =1; k<= DT.Rows.Count; k++)
                {

                    if((DT.Rows[k][TablesIndex[x-1, 2]].ToString() == "") && (DT.Rows[k-1][TablesIndex[x-1, 2]].ToString() != "") && (DT.Rows[k+1][TablesIndex[x-1, 2]].ToString() == "") || (DT.Columns.Count - 1 == j))
                    {
                        DT.Rows.Add();
                        //Linha Fim
                        TablesIndex[x-1, 3] = k;

                        if (UltimaTabela == false )
                        { 
                        x += 1;
                        int[,] temp = new int[x, 6];
                        if (TablesIndex != null)
                        {
                            Array.Copy(TablesIndex, temp, Math.Min(TablesIndex.Length, temp.Length));
                            TablesIndex = temp;
                            Entra = true;
                        }
                        }
                        break;

                    }

            }

            }

        }
```